# What is the name of the "<<" and ">>" operators?

Tags: c++, symbols

I'm wondering if there is a standard name for the "<<" and ">>" operators? This is mostly in the context of teaching C++ and using those operators as part of stream input/output. If I need to read code or prompt for student responses (such as `cout << "Hello";`), I'm not sure how to verbalize those symbols. Is there a convention when reading them out loud?

Improved version of this question: [How do you read the "<<" and ">>" symbols out loud?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42775451/how-do-you-read-the-and-symbols-out-loud)

Comment: Insertion/extraction operators.

Comment: This-a-way, and that-a-way.

Comment: Funny thing is, even my team has used it for many years, we still calls it `<<` as "iip-iip", and `>>` as "aad-aad" (sound like an animal), because standard name is too long and not-cute. As we have a consistent way to communicate, we have no problem.

Comment: left-shift and right-shift

Comment: I disagree that this is a duplicate of the linked question; those answers are in regard to a bit-shifting context, and this is not.

Comment: @javaLover I'm curious, how did you end up with "iip-iip" and "aad-add" ?

Comment: @Quentin  Long story.  At first, `<<` is called `bit/left-shift`, then because of its repetitive looking, it becomes `shift-shift`.  When looked more closely, it is an orange beak of a yellow chick moving and begging for food - `chip chip`.  The chick has beak but no real head (it has only `<<`) and also eating a food, so sound is a bit distorted but cute - `iip-iip`.   Another opposite `>>` chick becomes jealous about food, so it begs with an ugly black-crow sound `(k)aarrr-(k)aarrr`.  Merged with  `ta-dad` when an answer is wrong in a game show ("You should gimme food!")  -> `aad-add`.

Answer (score 7):

When not overloaded, *left-shift* and *right-shift* and some people call them that even when used with streams, but *insertion* and *extraction* is a lot more common in that context. They are also sometimes informally called *put to* and *get from*. IIRC, Stroustrup favoured that last form.

Comment: So, for example: How would you verbalize `cout << "Hello";`?

Comment: "Insert Hello to c-out", or "put Hello to c-out"

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 6):

According to [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/)'s documentation:

> This operator (<<) applied to an output stream is known as **insertion operator**.
>
> ...

And from the same website

> This operator (>>) applied to an input stream is known as **extraction operator**.
>
> ...

Answer (score 4):

In his book "The C++ Programming Language", C++11, bjarne stroustrup has called << "put to" and >> "get from".

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

`<<` is the insertion operator. Note when you write

```
cout << "Some text";
```

The arrows are pointing to the stream. You're inserting the text into the stream.

`>>` is the extraction operator. When you write

```
cin >> some_var;
```

You're extracting a value from the stream.

Comment: So: How would you verbalize cout << "Hello";?

Comment: "c-out some text". Since insertion is the most common you'll do on `cout` (at least in my experience), it's kind of implied. For a streams where both insertions and extractions are common, you might say "Insert/extract some text into/from the stream"

Answer (score 0):

Those are officially bitwise shift operators (e.g., `1 << 3` is 8), but they're often overloaded as stream insertion/stream extraction operators (as in the cout example you gave).

Comment: So, for example: How would you verbalize `cout << "Hello";`?

Comment: I'd probably say ”write Hello to cout”.

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't answer the question.